# Infinite set of natural numbers and the set difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we were to take $M \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, and $M$ has infinitely many elements, can the complement $\mathbb{N} \backslash M$ still be infinite?

I'm guessing no, since the cardinalities of $M$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are the same. If it were to be $\mathbb{R}$, then we can find an $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ that is infinite and $\mathbb{R} \backslash M $ is still infinite?

Or is there a better proof for this?

Comment: Take the set of even integers.

Comment: For the reals, take $M = [0,1]$

Comment: Oh yea true... Why didn't I think about that. Thanks @DavidMitra!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The set of prime numbers, $\mathbb{P} \subset \mathbb{N}$ is infinite, and the set of composite (non-prime) numbers, $\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{P}$ is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

let E be set of even integers and O be set of odd integers then E ⊆ N and O ⊆ N and you can clearly observe E\N and O\N is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

As already has been said in comments, it is not generally true.

The reason is that if $x$ is an infinite cardinal number, then $x + x = x$, and both $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ obviously have infinite cardinalities. So, infinite sets always accept a decomposition into two sets with the same cardinality.